# Remove Branch and Commit Option from Jenkins Blueocean UI for Pipeline Job

Tags: git, jenkins, branch

I am using jenkins blueocean plugin to create Pipeline view of my jenkins job. The use case of my pipeline job is something different. I am not using it, to make build from the code integrated with git. Hence, In blueocean UI we are getting some unused information like "Branch", "Commit" and "No Changes". Is there any way to remove it from the UI.

Attached Screenshot: [image: Blueocean UI in my case]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add images rather as images than as links. This time I've done this for you - please see [the editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more information on formatting.

Comment: Thanks @jaySf for your help!